# Does SaveChanges violate Restful conventions?

Tags: breeze

I just finished watching John Pappa's pluralsight training video and was just blown away with how all of the pieces came together.

As I am digesting what I learned I am left with one serious after thought.

As incredibly easy breeze makes the queryable part and the CUD part of data services, the CUD part seems to have too much of a proprietary webapi method signature.  It's easy to use and brilliant in how functional it is for its simplicity but we are used to Post, Put and Delete for the CUD part of things.  These individual WepApi methods are more to code but they allow explicitly stated logic for saving things.  I, for example, only do soft deletes, so an explicitly declared Delete webapi function would allow me to insert a deleted record in to my audit table, mark the record deleted by setting the DeletedDate and then actually not delete the record.  Sometimes, based on the role of the person, you want to do overposting protections.  For example CreatedDate might be a property in the entity but a client side forced/invalid change in that property should not auto-update the column on the server side.  Or, while part of a ServiceTicket entity, the assigned service technician should never be able to be updated by the client unless the user has certain roles.

Where and how can these server side interventions be coded in the SaveChanges method in breeze?  And what happens when people expect a fully Post/Put/Delete like "api" and breeze only provides a single method like SaveChanges?

And finally I am assuming that breeze uses the proprietary ContextProvider only because the odata implementation doesn't yet do the expand and select, right?  Are there any plans to do away with that extra layer if and once wepapi odata fully implements all the odata verbs?  How, if at all, has the 2012 Update 2 changed things in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Ok - I just saw this: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider#SaveInterception, so that kind of answers the security aspect but not the other parts of my question like Put/Post/Delete

Comment: We are working with the OData team to use more of their implementation once they support $expand and $select. They also need to support ( per the OData spec) metadata with principal and dependent constraints. They have agreed that these are all on their list.